# How to add parameter to Url in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to pass the matchday to the URL for the Http connection. I know I can't get a value from the EditText in the doInBackground method so I thought to get the value in the onPreExecute method. Of I then add the variable to the URL, the program doesn't recognise the String. I saw on StackOverflow you need to add the parameters in the execute method but I don't really have got that part of the explanation.

Does anyone have an idea how to add the matchday to the URL, entered in the EditText matchdayText?

Thanks in advance!
Rob Nickmans

CODE:

```
    package ga.rndevelopment.footballpronostics;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText matchdayText;
    TextView responseView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    static final String API_KEY = "HIDDEN";
    static final String API_URL = "http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/PL/matches/?matchday=";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        responseView = findViewById(R.id.responseView);
        matchdayText = findViewById(R.id.matchdayText);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        Button queryButton = findViewById(R.id.queryButton);
        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new FetchData().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            responseView.setText("");
            String matchDay = matchdayText.getText().toString();
            String apiUrl = API_URL + matchDay;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token", API_KEY);

                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                } finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if (response == null) {
                response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("INFO", response);
            responseView.setText(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't. It is already too late. You add the parameter to the URL string first, then construct the `URL`, then the `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

> First Create the connection using URL Connection.There by create
>   buffer writer and pass the all requested data in one single String
>   buffer variable there by it will take to concern URL and along with
>   Requested parameter and its values. Please go Through this Below
>   sample Example

```
 URL url = new URL("give your URL ");
 URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
 conn.setDoOutput(true);
 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));
        final StringBuilder reqstData = new StringBuilder(100);
        reqstData.append("&userId=").append(userId);
        reqstData.append("&roleId=").append(roleId);
        reqstData.append("&userName=").append(userName);
 out.write(reqstData);
 out.flush();
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: I could indeed just filter the data, but I'm planning to also change other things in the url, like the competition and so on. This is a nice plan B, but I saw another, better solution in other threads (I don't get it, but I know there's such an option). Thanks though for your answer!